# using eclipse to build rhapsody API compatible code

Tags: java, eclipse, rhapsody

I have some small code that i can build and run with:

```
setlocal
set PATH=C:\Rhapsody\Rhapsody_8_2_1\jdk\bin;%PATH%
javac java_test.java -cp c:\pathto\rhapsody.jar
java -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\username\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.2.1\Share\JavaAPI -cp c:\pathto\rhapsody.jar;. java_test
```

it compiles and runs without warning/error.

I would like to debug this so i downloaded latest eclipse version and set up a procjet.

I added the "C:\Rhapsody\Rhapsody_8_2_1\jdk\" as "rhap jdk" and selected this one in my project in the "java build Path" settings by setting the JRE system on the library tab to this (alternate jre) "rhap jdk".
I also added the rhapsody.jar as "external jar"

If i try to run the code it stops on the first rhapsody class with a class-loader exception that it cannot load the class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: rhapsody (Not found in java.library.path)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1348)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1318)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:552)
    at com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.RhapsodyAppServer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at ImportDependencies.main(ImportDependencies.java:181)
```

I also tried to set the environment variable (in the "run configuration") `java.library.path` to C:\Users\username\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.2.1\Share\JavaAPI and I also tried to add this directory as library directory.

What is the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because it's not loading the correct Rhapsody.dll. The folder with the rhapsody jar should look something like this:

[image]

I believe the one in there by default is the 64 bit dll, so just swapping it with the .dll in the WIN32 directory.

Comment: in my folder it is exactly reversed. i have a sub folder with 64bit. Also the rhapsody (and i guess its jdk) is 32bit. Does this conflict with a 64bit eclipse that is configured to use the 32bit jre?

Answer (score 0):

I think the application is looking for rhapsody.jar file so you need to add that file in the class path of the Java project.
The jar file can be found in the installation folder 8.2.1/share/JavaAPI/

There is one more trick, after you add the jar file to the project there is an option calle Native library location you need to set the value to the directory where this jar file is located
[image: Java Project Properties]